# Taylor expansion of inverse distance

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, tensors

In a physics exercise, the following is stated for ($x,x' \in \mathbb{R}^3, |x| \gg |x'| )$ :

> The expression of the potential follows immediately if one performs a Taylor expansion of
> the
> inverse distance, $1/|x −x′|$, as follows : $$ \frac{1}{|x-x'|} = \frac{1}{|x|} + \frac{x\cdot x'}{|x|^3}$$ Where the terms of order O($|x'|^2$) are suppressed.

I would use multiindexes to arrive at this expression. Because of how casualy it is stated, is there a quicker way ?

Comment: Looking back at it, it looks like they are applying the 1D Taylor expansion of $1/1- (x'/x)$ and adding as first order the projection of x' on x. Is there a quick way of justifying that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ because I'll definitely make typos with primes. Note that
\begin{align}
|x-y|^2=|x|^2-2x\cdot y+|y|^2
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
|x-y|&=|x|\sqrt{1-2\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^2}+\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}}
\end{align}
So, by defining $\epsilon:=-2\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^2}+\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}$, one has
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|x-y|}&=\frac{1}{|x|}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon}}
\end{align}
Since we assume $\frac{|y|}{|x|}\ll 1$, it follows by Cauchy-Schwarz that $|\epsilon|\leq 2\frac{|x||y|}{|x|^2}+\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}\ll 1$. This allows us to expand the quantity $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\epsilon}}=1-\frac{\epsilon}{2}+O(\epsilon^2)$ in powers of $\epsilon$. Then one can group things together to obtain your expansion:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|x-y|}&=\frac{1}{|x|}\left[1+\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^2}\right) \right]\\
&=\frac{1}{|x|}+\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^3}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\right)
\end{align}

---

I don't see any quicker way of obtaining this (and the higher order terms eg for the quadrupole are even more tedious to get right). It was probably mentioned so casually because physicists do such Taylor expansions all the time, so it is also expected that you as a student be familiar with such a calculational procedure.