# Asymptotic behavior of fundamental solution to Laplace's equation.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$ be compact. I want to prove that there exist $a,b > 0$ such that
\begin{align}
\left \vert \frac{1}{\lvert x -y \rvert} - \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert} - \frac{x \cdot y}{\lvert x \rvert^{3}} \right \vert \le \frac{a}{\lvert x \rvert^{3}}
\end{align}
for all $x$ such that $\lvert x \rvert \ge b$ and all $y \in K$. I'm not entirely sure how to go about this. I was thinking to perform a Taylor series expansion of \begin{align}
f(s) = \frac{s \lvert x \rvert }{\lvert x - s \lvert x \rvert y \rvert}
\end{align}
around $s = 0$, and then set $s = 1/\lvert x \rvert$. But perhaps there is a much simpler way?

Comment: do you mean $|x|^2$ in the denominator on the RHS?

Comment: I found this problem in a classical hydrodynamics text (Marine Hydrodynamics, Newman, p143). He claims that the remainder is $O(1/|x|^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Taylor expansion of Inverse Distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4208419/568204). The meaning of $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\right)$ is that there is a constant $A>0$ and a $\delta>0$ such that for all $(x,y)$ satisfying $\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\leq \delta$, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{|x-y|}-\frac{1}{|x|}-\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^3}\right|\leq A\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
To get the uniform estimate you have, we only need $K$ to be bounded, compactness is not necessary. So, suppose $K$ lies inside a ball of radius $M>0$. Then, provided $|x|\geq b:=\left(\frac{M^2}{\delta}\right)^{1/3}$, we have for each $y\in K$ that
\begin{align}
\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\leq M^2\cdot \frac{\delta}{M^2}=\delta
\end{align}
Hence, by the estimate $(*)$,
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{1}{|x-y|}-\frac{1}{|x|}-\frac{x\cdot y}{|x|^3}\right|\leq A\frac{|y|^2}{|x|^3}\leq \frac{AM^2}{|x|^3}.
\end{align}
In other words, we have $a=AM^2$.